# Array Serialization Issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, serialization, query-string

I'm storing some information which has been serialized by using jQuery into a MySQL database :

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $("#q35list").val($(this).sortable('serialize'));
        }
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

This stores the relevant information in the DB fine (via a .php save page).

However, when I return it and unserialize it using the following:

```
$arr = unserialize($results['q35list']);
if(!$arr) $arr=array();
var_dump($arr);
```

It' not an array! It's as follows:

```
string(55) "Set[]=2&Set[]=1&Set[]=3&Set[]=4&Set[]=5&Set[]=6&Set[]=7"
```

I am now at the point where I cannot see the wood from the trees...

Comment: Are you sure PHP serialization and jQuery serialization works the same way?

Comment: Was just wondering the same - looks like they don't!

Comment: Actually, what I should say, is there any eay way to get the order of the number in that last string?

Comment: See @Benz suggestion below. `parse_str()` would allow you to "unserialize" the stored jQuery's query string values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery serialization and PHP serialization are two separate things. jQuery focuses on being able to send the data through CGI (either GET or POST), PHP serialization focuses on storing structured data in a string.

**They are not interchangeable.**

You have to serialize and unserialize in the same platform, or it will not work.

Comment: Cheers Bart - just realized my error!  Just got to work out how to do that.  Thanks.

Comment: Just feed the serialized string to your jQuery and unserialize there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure, but can't you use the `parse_str()` function

Like this

```
parse_str($string, $array);
```

Where $string is the data from mysql and $array is the array you can use to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way simpler fix for your problem, but if nothing else works you can also use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to cut the string in parts and create your array.

Comment: Exactly what I have just done - not pretty but it works - thanks AnPel.

Comment: @Homer_J Not an optimal idea. See Benz's answer above.